# Different HashCodes for CryptoStream when Project is used within another Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

There is the following decrpytion function as shown in a .dll project.

```
private static string Decrypt(string val)
    {
        byte[] cryIV = { 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50 };
        byte[] cryKey;
        byte[] crystr = Convert.FromBase64String(val);
        byte[] decstr = new byte[crystr.Length - 1];
        RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
        RijndaelManaged cryRdm = new RijndaelManaged();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(crystr);
        ICryptoTransform cryTrD;

        cryKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc".GetHashCode().ToString());
        cryTrD = cryRdm.CreateDecryptor(cryKey, cryIV);

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryTrD, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        try
        {
            cs.Read(decstr, 0, decstr.Length);
        }
        catch (CryptographicException exc)
        {
            throw exc;
        }



        ms.Close();
        cs.Close();

        return ((string)Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decstr)).Replace("\0", string.Empty);

    }
```

The function works fine as part of the main project, but when I use the .dll in another project, the function throws the error `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed`.

I've narrowed it down to the line

```
cryKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abc".GetHashCode().ToString());
```

which returns different values, depending on the referencing project.

How can I make this work, when the .dll is used in the second project?

I've tried to set `crKey` to the values which are assigned, when the function works, like this:

```
cryIV = { 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50 };
```

but this did not work either.

I also could replicate the behaviour on a second computer.

I use Visual Studio 2019. I think that the problem could be caused be different project settings, since the code works fine from the same .dll, if called from one project.

Comment: From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.gethashcode?view=netcore-3.1): The hash code itself is not guaranteed to be stable. Hash codes for identical strings can differ across .NET implementations, across .NET versions, and across .NET platforms (such as 32-bit and 64-bit) for a single version of .NET. In some cases, they can even differ by application domain. This implies that two subsequent runs of the same program may return different hash codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the notice about using [`GetHashCode()` on strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.gethashcode?view=netcore-3.1) in the "Remarks" section:

> **Important**
>
> If two string objects are equal, the GetHashCode method returns identical values. However, there is not a unique hash code value for each unique string value. Different strings can return the same hash code.
>
> The hash code itself is not guaranteed to be stable. Hash codes for identical strings can differ across .NET implementations, across .NET versions, and across .NET platforms (such as 32-bit and 64-bit) for a single version of .NET. In some cases, they can even differ by application domain. This implies that two subsequent runs of the same program may return different hash codes.
>
> As a result, hash codes should never be used outside of the application domain in which they were created, they should never be used as key fields in a collection, and they should never be persisted.
>
> Finally, don't use the hash code instead of a value returned by a cryptographic hashing function if you need a cryptographically strong hash. For cryptographic hashes, use a class derived from the System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm or System.Security.Cryptography.KeyedHashAlgorithm class.
>
> For more information about hash codes, see Object.GetHashCode.

That is exactly what you are using at `"abc".GetHashCode().ToString()`. Use the mentioned classes to generate your key.